# Expression for “SelectLayerByAttribute_management” with value of a cursor in the field name?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, select-by-attribute

Within a script I create a new file, which has a dynamic value in the attribute name. This also changes the name of the attribute [FID] in each file. During a query in a file I have to use this attribute. So I have to create the field name for the query expression. But this is where I fail because of the syntax of all the quotation marks and backslashes.

The "normal" (undynamic) query would look like this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(
    "Union",
    'NEW_SELECTION',
    "\"FID_4113_T\" <> -1 AND \"FID_4113_L\" <> -1"
)
```

Doc: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm

My problem is that I cannot integrate the value of the cursor `(row[0].zfill(4))` into the field name `[FID_*row[0].zfill(4)*_T]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `format()` method to include specific values inside your strings. Furthermore, I think the field name does not have to be inside quotes but I may be wrong. You could write the following inside your `for` loop:

```py
for row in cursor:
    fid = row[0].zfill(4)
    query = '''FID_{}_T <> -1 AND FID_{}_L <> - 1'''.format(fid, fid)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Union", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
```

If it does not work, give it a try by quoting the field names. No need to escape the quotes as the query has triple single quotes.

Comment: it works nearly perfect 8-) I had only to change the second line into
fid = str(row[0]).zfill(4)

Thanks a lot for your super fast help